# Submit a Form with a drop down list doesn't work

Tags: html, forms, list, drop-down-menu, submit

I want to post to the same page some information. But when i have the drop down list in my form it won't submit the values.

When i delet the drop down list from the form, the form can be submitted.

Thats my HTML code:

```
<?php
     echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'" method="post">';
?>
<label for="file">File:</label>
<input type="file" name="uploadfile[]" id="uploadfile" multiple="" /><br>
Speicherordner:
<select id="selectfolder" name="selectfolder" style="width: 250px">
<option value="/">1 - dir ("/..")</option>
<option value="dir1/">2 - dir ("/dir2/..")</option>
<option value="dir2/">3 - dir ("/dir3/..")</option>
<option value="dir3/">4 - dir ("/dir4/..")</option>
<option value="dir4/">5 - dir ("/dir5/..")</option>
<option value="dir5/">6 - dir ("/dir6/..")</option>
<option value="dir6/">7 - dir ("/events/..")</option>
<option value="dir7/">8 - dir ("/dir7/..")</option>
<option value="dir8/">9 - dir ("/dir8/..")</option>
```

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Upload">
```

and that is my php Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
  echo '<div id="hidden" style="display:block">';
  $serv=$_POST["selectfolder"]; 
  echo "hallo";
  echo $serv;
}
```

Comment: Your `<input type="submit">` is outside of your `<form>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

submit button should be inside the  tag. Also,

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```

is much better than echo-ing the `<form>` tag

Answer (score 0):

surely your submit button should be within the form tags??
if that does not work, try removing the "/" from the DDL values...